# Using sed to replace variable name and its value

Tags: replace, sed

In many PHP files I have defined the variable `$_PATHROOT` like this

```
$_PATHROOT = '../../../../';
```

And I would to replace it with `define()`:

```
define('_PATHROOT', '../../../../');
```

Of course, the value ../../../../ differs from one file to another.

Would it be possible with linux sed command line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible.

The following command should work for any script (it worked for me on a test file):

`sed -ri "s/^[$]_PATHROOT = '(([.][.]\/)+)';$/define('_PATHROOT', '\1');/" FILEPATH`

where you replace FILEPATH with the path of the file to be edited.

This command assumes that the line you want to change is exactly

`$_PATHROOT = '../../';`

except that there may be any positive number of "../"s. Any variations in whitespace will throw it off, so if that varies across files you'll need to modify it.

Credit to Kent for the idea of using `[$]` instead of a mess of backslashes as `$` has special meaning in both bash and sed.

Answer (score 0):

This sed one-liner works for the given example:

```
sed -r "s/^[$](\w+)(.*);/define('\1'\2);/;s/=/,/"
```

:

```
kent$  sed -r "s/^[$](\w+)(.*);/define('\1'\2);/;s/=/,/"<<<"\$_PATHROOT = '../../../../';"  
define('_PATHROOT' , '../../../../');
```

Comment: Yes but the value may change, it can be for example '../../' and I would like to execute the sed command in a find command `find -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i ...`. Is it possible?

Comment: I imagine the PHP files will contain other lines as well. Wouldn't this pattern likely affect other unrelated lines, given how many lines in PHP start with `$`?

Comment: It depends on the file, they don't have the same number of lines starting with `$`.

Comment: I didn't hard code the value part, so it should work on other values too. @LondonSmith